# Does txInfoValidRange adjust as time continues on?

Tags: plutus, context, intervals, txinfovalidrange

Given that the function A `contains` B is true when all of B is contained in A, and false otherwise, wouldn't that mean that the `txInfoValidRange info` would have to move its "start point" in order to return true? Below is my thinking :)

`` checkDeadline = from (deadline p) `contains` txInfoValidRange info ``

In this code, `from (deadline p)` contains all of the slots from some deadline to pos infinity.

---Below is where I think I am wrong---

`txInfoValidRange info` is just a SlotRange from the creation of the transaction to pos infinity.

So how then can the `deadline p` contain the `txInfoValidRange info` without the `txInfoValidRange info` adjusting its starting point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. No, we don't move anything.

I think that the naming is confusing. It shouldn't be called `deadline` because in my opinion `deadline` is when something ends. In our case, it's the other way around. We allow taking funds only AFTER the deadline.

Please take a look at the picture. We shouldn't allow Tx1, only Tx2.

[image]

In our case [deadline, infinity] doesn't contain Tx1.validRange contains Tx2.validRange.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think my confusion stems from the txInfoValidRange. Where does the valid range of a transaction start? And more importantly, what factors decide the valid range of a transaction?

Comment: From my understanding you should specify validRange yourself during transaction construction. It could be done with `mustValidateIn` function from `Ledger.Contrains` module. You can find an example here https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/src/Week01/EnglishAuction.hs#L325

Comment: Seems to me like this deadline thing is redundant then. If you can simply specify the range when a transaction should validate, you can just set the start of that somewhere in the future. Lars is trolling us!

Comment: @IsaacPadberg Hmm, I don't think that you can put totally random valid ranges. From my understanding current slot should be a member of validRange. Check out this function https://alpha.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/src/Ledger.Index.html#checkSlotRange

Comment: I failed to keep in mind the structure of validation scripts and transactions. Simply by constructing a transaction after the deadline, the validRange of the transaction will be contained in the deadline->Infinity. So obvious! Thanks for the help Yanis :)